# How to display the next span text when hovered over another span

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
            <div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
                <span class="profileLabel">Contact Number:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCliDate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="profileLabelValue"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("body").on("hover", ".profileLabel" , function () {
        alert($(this).next(".profileLabelValue").text());
    });
});
```

I am looking to show the text of the `profileLabelValue` class `span` when hovered over `profileLabel` class `span`. With my code, nothing is happening.

How can I accomplish this, as the method I am currently trying is not working.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML and not the asp?

Comment: I figured it out. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of `hover` I had to use `mouseover`.

I changed the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("mouseover", ".profileLabel", function (e) {
        alert($(this).parent().next("div").find("span").first().text());
    });
});
```

In case someone else needs it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("mouseover", ".profileLabel", function (e) {
        alert($(this).parent().next("div").find("span").first().text());
    });
});
```

Comment: This also worked for me. Thanks. The `hover` was the issue, it was `mouseover`. silly me!

Comment: it's all my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'mouseover' instead of 'hover'.

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/on/)